# deleting images by clicking correspondent buttons

Tags: php, javascript, image, file, button

I have a folder / directory containing lots of images and other folders / directories.

**I am showing the preview of these files using following code:**

```
<?php
      $images=array();  
        $dir_handler = opendir('test') or die("Unable to open path");  
        $i=0;    
        while($file = readdir($dir_handler))
        {            
        if(is_dir($file)) 
        continue;        
        else if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php')
        {                    
        $images[$i]=$file;
        $i++;     
        }       
        }      
        sort($images);

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($images); $i++) 
        {              

        echo "<a href=".chr(34).$path.$images[$i].chr(34)."><img style='border:1px solid #666666; width:100px;height:100px; margin: 10px;' src='test/".$images[$i]."'/><input type='button' value='nok[]'></a>";

        }        closedir($dir);
?>
```

The problem is that I want to assign a separate button to each file (to each image or folder), So that by clicking each button, its corresponding image (or folder / directory) gets deleted from the main folder and no more being shown as a preview.

Another small problem is that the preview of folders are not being shown with the above code. Why? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to delete the image/directory from the server?  Or do you want to stop displaying them?

Answer (score 0):

You are always displaying an image, you need to do a check if the $images array value is an image or a folder. Then do something different with the display.

To delete a file or folder, use these functions respectively:

```
unlink();
rmdir();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

To add a list of folders before your images change your code to:

```
<?php
  $images=array();  
  $folders = array();
    $dir_handler = opendir('test') or die("Unable to open path");  
    $i=0;    
    while($file = readdir($dir_handler))
    {            
    if(is_dir($file)) {
         $folders[count($folders)] = $file;
    }   
    else if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php')
    {                    
    $images[$i]=$file;
    $i++;     
    }       
    }      
    sort($images);

    foreach($folders as $folder){

     echo "<a href='#'>$folder</a>";
    }

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($images); $i++) 
    {              

    echo "<a href=".chr(34).$path.$images[$i].chr(34)."><img style='border:1px solid #666666; width:100px;height:100px; margin: 10px;' src='test/".$images[$i]."'/><input type='button' value='nok[]'></a>";

    }   

 closedir($dir);
?>
```

Then all you have to do is build out the visual elements of a folder in your view and link to a function that will do your unlink() and rmdir() where needed.

Comment: thank you, but my main problem is not related to deleting operation. My question is that how can I define images and buttons so that they become correspondent. for instance should their name be something like $images[i] and  $buttons[i]? I have problem with defining them as arrays that are corespondent one by one.

Comment: Edited to explain how to add folders to your code and display them before the images.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions here.

First question: Why won't preview of folders show? This is because you show previews by looping through the $images array, but you do not add directories to that array (see your code where you check if it is_dir and then invoke "continue;"). If you want to include the directories, then you should include them in the $images array (or do something else with them).

Second question: How to do the deleting? You need to either extend your existing PHP script or write another one. You would create a link on the delete icon; the link's href would be to the new (or existing) PHP script and you would pass in as parameters the folder or file to be deleted. If it is a folder, then use rmdir(). If it is a file, then use unlink(). I can help you more with this later, if you need it.